# Materialize CSS change display of selected values

Tags: materialize

I have this line of codes using Materialize CSS select elements

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

However when I selected items, I don't want to display the values of the items selected but something like "1 option selected" or "2 options selected". How can I achieve this using Materialize CSS?

I have searched the forums for a possible solution but with no success.